# signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: discord.js, segmentation-fault

I posted about this a few days ago, but after following their suggestion it still does not seem to be working. Any idea why? I am using replit and uptime to host the bot.
I am new to coding and I just can't figure out whats wrong

Figured I would ask you guys and see if you have any idea why. Please lemme know if you have any ideas

```
const prefix = '?';
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES"
  ]
});

const config = process.env;
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(bot.user.username + ' is online.')
});
//CONSTANT COMMANDS



//Text Commands

bot.on('messageCreate', (msg) => {
if(msg.author.bot || msg.channel.type === "dm")
  return;
  const messageArray = msg.content.split(' ');
  const cmd = messageArray[0];
  const args = msg.content.substring(msg.content.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  const prefix = config.prefix;

if(cmd.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'discord' ) {
msg.channel.send({
  content: 'https://discord.gg/RehTqdDpEm'
})
}

if(cmd.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'realm' ) {
msg.channel.send({
  content: 'https://realms.gg/5T7DrRwbS7o'
})
}

if(cmd.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'yada' ) {
msg.channel.send({
  content: 'yada'
})
}



//Embed Commands

  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "help") {
  let embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Command List")
    .setDescription("**?Player Description**- Shows a description of all the players. \n **realm**- Sends a realm invite \n **?factions**- Shows the factions of this season and their members \n **?info {faction}**- Shows the lore and banner of a faction \n **?help**- Shows this help menu \n **?quote**- Sends a random quote from the server \n **?world**- sends the world lore.")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})
  }


  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "world") {
  let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("World Lore")
    .setDescription("lore")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})
  }


  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "info giraduan") {
  let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("The Giraduan Dominion")
    .setDescription("lore")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})
  }

  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "info rpa") {
  let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Rerualin Preservation Association")
    .setDescription("faction lore")
.setColor("RANDOM"
    )
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})
  }

  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "player description") {
  let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Player Descriptions")
    .setDescription("oops no info for you")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})
  }

  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "character example") {
  let embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Example Character")
    .setDescription("description")
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877727121341026304/904443409614401546/YIN_YANG-removebg-preview.png')
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed2]})
  }
});



//Game Commands 




bot.login(config.token);
```

Comment: Try deleting and reinstalling Node and NPM, then do the same for all of your depencancies

Comment: @Elitezen Okay, do i fixed that issue. However, i continually get the issue below.


Node.js v17.0.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Delta-Community@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the Delta-Community@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-11-15T01_15_49_884Z-debug.log
exit status 1
